# How do I copy the address from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do I select and copy the address from Google Maps? I need to copy the info to a [restaurant](https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Liberty/@40.7526187,-73.9872171,17z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sliberty!3m4!1s0x89c258fc25535bc5:0x9551a76f6f9455a8!8m2!3d40.7499044!4d-73.9855979) into a Meetup. It won't select the text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you mean. The address in the information card seems to be non-selectable with the mouse and dragging over the text.

However, if you *triple*-click the address, the text is highlighted and can be copied with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or right-click and choosing "Copy").

[image: screen shot with address selected]

---

Since I originally posted this, it seems that Google have fixed a bug on their end. I can now select the address by dragging with the mouse.